# Importing Images into Image boxes

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to import an image into an "Image" box in c#.

I have found when doing it in XAML it's just

```
source = "file location"
```

but when I try the following code in C#

```
myimage.source = "image.png"
```

my image being the name of the "Image" box it just returns this error:

```
Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'
```

when looking online everyone seems to just quote using picture box but I don't have access to picture boxes, and if I didn't and point in the program "myimage" is displaying a live video stream. So, an image box is required I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) out.

In C# it would be:

```
Image myImage = new Image();
myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("myPicture.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Comment: Thank that has removed the error although no image is displayed in "myImage" Still for some reason. I have tried with .png and .jpg images.

Comment: You should use the Image object.
If you want to place it in a picture box then place it there, the myImage object won't show up since it's just a class that handles Images.

Answer (score 3):

```
picBox.Image = Image.FromFile("image.png");
```

you may want to create a new URI which points to the actual image

Answer (score 1):

Try this code using an openFileDialog1 object :
Double click on your picturebox and write :

```
private void imagePictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            imagePictureBox.ImageLocation = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
    }
```

if your image is in an 'images folder' into your application folder, just write :

```
imagePictureBox.ImageLocation = "images/YourImage.png";
```